# How to do a "Do While" with a condition?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to do a cycle, where IF the condition is true and cell n index (column E) is the same as cell's n+1 index, to copy  the column C value into column G.

Unfortunately last C column value is not copied to column G, so i simply resolved it with a string:

```
Sheets("Report KIT").Range("G" & n) = Sheets("Report KIT").Range("C" & n).Value
```

after Do While. Can anyone help with it please? Thanks

```
    Sub Macroarea1()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastRow1 As Long, LastRow3 As Long
Dim i, n As Integer, x As Integer, y As Integer
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Report KIT")

    If Sheets("Migrazioni").Range("F" & 7) = "si" Then
    n = Sheets("Migrazioni").Range("N" & 7).Value
    Do While _
Sheets("Report KIT").Range("E" & n) = Sheets("Report KIT").Range("E" & n + 1)
Sheets("Report KIT").Range("G" & n) = Sheets("Report KIT").Range("C" & n).Value
n = n + 1
Loop
Sheets("Report KIT").Range("G" & n) = Sheets("Report KIT").Range("C" & n).Value
End If
```

End Sub

[image]

Comment: Do while tests the logic before doing the code.  What you are saying is if the current cell does not equal the next do nothing.  You will want an `or` statement in your `Do While` to check if the cell above is equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleaned up your looping a bit and added a check for the `E` column value first and modified the loop to check to make sure each row meets the initial `E` column value to test it. I tested this with your sample data it produced the result you wanted. Sometimes these conditional loops can be tricky to figure out!

```
Sub Macroarea1()

    Dim wsR As Worksheet, wsN As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastRow1 As Long, LastRow3 As Long
    Dim i, n As Integer, x As Integer, y As Integer

    Set wsR = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Report KIT")
    Set wsN = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Migrazioni")

    If wsN.Range("F7") = "si" Then

        n = wsN.Range("N7").Value
        i = wsR.Range("E" & n).Value

        Do Until wsR.Range("E" & n) <> i
            wsR.Range("G" & n).Value = wsR.Range("C" & n).Value
            n = n + 1
        Loop 

    End If

End Sub
```